# How to map a Map Object in Scala Slick

Tags: java, scala, slick

I want to use Scala Slick as FRM in my Scala project. I have following case class to map to table.

```
case class Person(name: String, pairs: Map[String, String])
```

How I can map this case class to Slick?

```
class Person(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Double)](tag, "PERSON") {
  def name = column[String]("NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
  ???
  def * = (name, ???)
}
val person = TableQuery[Person]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, in relational databases, key-value pairs can be stored as a seperate table:

something like:

```
CREATE TABLE person_pairs (person_id LONG, key TEXT, value TEXT)
```

Something similar works for sequences and other structures.

However, if you are using postgres, you can use an `hstore` column using the [slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) extension library. This will map your hstore (which is basically a set of key-value pairs) to a Map, which is what you are looking for